# Cmake adds nonexisting lib into linklibs.rsp

Tags: c, cmake, mingw

I am using cmake 3.20 for a C project in VSCode with MinGW.

I have several nested CMakeLists.txt and also use some imported libraries.

```
├─ src
│  ├─ Application
│  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  │  ├─ config
│  │  │  ├─ config_serial.c
│  │  │  ├─ config_serial.h
│  │  └─ main.c
│  ├─ Common
│  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  │  ├─ common.c
│  │  ├─ common.h
│  │  └─ common.h.in
│  ├─ ErrorHandler
│  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  │  ├─ error_handler.c
│  │  └─ error_handler.h
```

It was working fine until I decided to do some restructuring, where I decided to take the  `config`folder right under src and make a seperate library for it.

For the external libraries I use

```
# SET EXTERNAL LIBRARY PATH FOR ESX3CM LIBRARY
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/esx3cm")
find_path(ESX3CM_INC NAMES "stwtypes.h" REQUIRED)

# ADD IMPORTED LIBRARY ESX3CM
add_library(ESX3CM STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET ESX3CM PROPERTY
                            IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/esx3cm/libesx3cm.a")

# LINK ESX3CM LIB
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ESX3CM)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${ESX3CM_INC}")
```

linklibs.rsp before restructuring

```
  ../../libErrorHandler.a ../../../extern/esx3cm/libesx3cm.a ../../../extern/esx_3cm_osy/GCC_4_6_6_1/libesx3cm_osy_server.a ../../../extern/lwip/liblwip_esx3cm-Os.a ../../libCOMMON_WIN32.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

Now I get a linker error saying it cannot find -lSTATIC.

When I check the linklibs.rsp file I can see all my libs plus an entry -lSTATIC.
After restructuring I get

```
 ../../libConfig.a ../../libErrorHandler.a ../../libConfig.a ../../../extern/esx3cm/libesx3cm.a ../../../extern/esx_3cm_osy/GCC_4_6_6_1/libesx3cm_osy_server.a ../../../extern/lwip/liblwip_esx3cm-Os.a ../../libCOMMON_WIN32.a -lSTATIC -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

Deleting this entry and recompile the project seems to work.

Any ideas how this -lSTATIC ends up in the list of libraries?

Thx
Andy

Comment: "*I am using...I have...*". Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Describing code/build setup in words alone is almost never clear enough.

Comment: @kaylum I added some more details

Comment: Why do you have the word `IMPORTED` in `add_library(ESX3CM STATIC IMPORTED)`?

Comment: @BrechtSanders It is a library which i do not build on my own. From what I've seen in the manual, thats (one) way to do it.

Comment: Edit: I don't know exactly what was the issue, but it works now. Maybe there was one target_link_library too much...